# How do you start 2 threads at exactly the same instant?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, race-condition

For a test case I'm writing I would like to start 2 threads at exactly the same time, with the intention of forcing a race condition or a deadlock, to ensure that my code under test handles the situation correctly.   I'm not exactly sure how to signal the threads to start at exactly the same time.  Can someone show me how to signal 2 threads to start at exactly the same time?

The worker1.Start() and worker2.Start() calls are almost at the same time but not close enough to expose the bug I'm trying to fix.

Here is my test case.

```
[TestMethod]
public void test()
{
  var target = new TestableErqProtocolTools();
  var firstUri = HEDataScope.Scope.BusinessObjectServerUris[0].AbsoluteUri;

  var worker1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(target.TestableAddServerUrlsFromScope));
  var worker2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(target.TestableAddServerUrlsFromScope));

  var startEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

  worker1.Start();
  worker2.Start();

  StringAssert.StartsWith(target.DefaultRemoteServerUrl, firstUri, "DefaultRemoteServerUrl is {0}"
            , String.IsNullOrEmpty(target.DefaultRemoteServerUrl) ? "<empty>" : target.DefaultRemoteServerUrl);      
}
```

Comment: Event if you would be able to start 2 threads at the exact same moment, you have no control over their execution since this is manage by the scheduler. For an easy understanding of this, start 10 threads in a row with their only task is print ("hello I am thread # (threadNumber)). The output wont be in order. You will need to use Mutex and other sync object to manipulate the timing of your threads

Comment: You do not have that much control over thread start time. Perhaps rephrase your question in terms of the condition you are trying to replicate. For example, if it is a race condition you are trying to reproduce, you could ask "How do I increase the likelihood that race condition X will happen?"

Comment: Didn't MS Chess seek to address this kind of testing (heisenbugs from thread timing)? MS research seems to be down ATM, so it's difficult to follow up. http://chesstool.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot control it, and with one processing unit, only one thing can happen at a time.
What you can do is to use [Barriers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997287.aspx) to synchronize threads to a position in logical time.

Answer (score 3):

You can't start the threads at exactly the same time. You can not do it on a single processor machine. And you can not enforce it on a multi processor machine.

So keep on testing many many times. And do a code review with parallelism and multithreading problems in mind.